# problem in adding image to JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I'm having problems in adding a picture into JFrame, something is missing probebly or written wrong.
here are the classes:

main class:

```
public class Tester

    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            BorderLayoutFrame borderLayoutFrame = new BorderLayoutFrame();
            borderLayoutFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            borderLayoutFrame.setSize(600,600);
            borderLayoutFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

public class BorderLayoutFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
 {
     private JButton buttons[]; // array of buttons to hide portions
     private final String names[] = { "North", "South", "East", "West", "Center" };
     private BorderLayout layout; // borderlayout object
     private PicPanel picture = new PicPanel();

     // set up GUI and event handling

     public BorderLayoutFrame()
     {
         super( "Philosofic Problem" );
         layout = new BorderLayout( 5, 5 ); // 5 pixel gaps
         setLayout( layout ); // set frame layout
         buttons = new JButton[ names.length ]; // set size of array

         // create JButtons and register listeners for them

         for ( int count = 0; count < names.length; count++ ) 
         {
             buttons[ count ] = new JButton( names[ count ] );
             buttons[ count ].addActionListener( this );
         }
         add( buttons[ 0 ], BorderLayout.NORTH ); // add button to north
         add( buttons[ 1 ], BorderLayout.SOUTH ); // add button to south
         add( buttons[ 2 ], BorderLayout.EAST ); // add button to east
         add( buttons[ 3 ], BorderLayout.WEST ); // add button to west
         add( picture, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // add button to center
    }

    // handle button events

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {

    } 

  }
```

I'v tried to add the image into the center of layout.

here is the image class:

```
public class PicPanel extends JPanel
{
    Image img;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;

    public PicPanel()
    {
        super();
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("table.jpg");
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         super.paintComponents(g);
         if ((width <= 0) || (height <= 0))
         {
             width = img.getWidth(this);
             height = img.getHeight(this);
         }
         g.drawImage(img,0,0,width,height,this);
    }
}
```

Please your help, what is the problem?
thanks

BTW: i'm using eclipse, which directory the image suppose to be in?

Comment: good question - what exactly *is* the problem? ;-)

Comment: Have you tried just adding the image panel to an empty `JFrame`?  What happens if you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several issues with the code you've posted:

- You should use `getContentPane().add()` instead of simply `add()` in your `BorderLayoutFrame` class.
- You should really use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to launch your JFrame from the tester class. Something like this:

---

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.setProperty("DEBUG_UI", "true");

        BorderLayoutFrame blf = new BorderLayoutFrame();
        blf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        blf.setSize(600,600);
        blf.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

- Don't use Toolkit to load images! In the following code, if "Table.jpg" is in the same package as PicPanel, the image will correctly load.

---

```
public PicPanel() {
    super();
    try {
        rUrl = getClass().getResource("Table.jpg");
        if (rUrl != null) {
            img = ImageIO.read(rUrl);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PicPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

- In `PicPanel.PaintComponent()` you call `super.paintComponents()` is the 's' a typeo?
- In `PicPanel.PaintComponent()`, you **don't** need all the width/height stuff, just do this:

  `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);`

And avoid the call to super.paintComponent all together because you're painting an image, why do you want the panel to paint at all?

My final implementation of your stuff:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.setProperty("DEBUG_UI", "true");

                BorderLayoutFrame blf = new BorderLayoutFrame();
                blf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                blf.setSize(600,600);
                blf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}

class BorderLayoutFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private final BorderLayout layout;
    private final JButton[] buttons;
    private final String names[] = {"North", "South", "East", "West", "Center"};

    public BorderLayoutFrame() {
        super( "Philosofic Problem" );
        layout = new BorderLayout( 5, 5 );
        getContentPane().setLayout( layout );
        buttons = new JButton[ names.length ];

        for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(names[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        getContentPane().add(buttons[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttons[1], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttons[2], BorderLayout.EAST);
        getContentPane().add(buttons[3], BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(new PicPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ignore
    }

}

class PicPanel extends JPanel
{
    private URL rUrl;
    private BufferedImage img;



    public PicPanel() {
        super();
        try {
            rUrl = getClass().getResource("UtilBtn.png");
            if (rUrl != null) {
                img = ImageIO.read(rUrl);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PicPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, if you are using the path `"table.jpg"` then you need that image to be at the top level of the project.

For a bit more info on the Eclipse project structure see [this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437382/how-does-relative-file-path-works-in-eclipse)

You may want to try using an [`ImageIcon`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to display the image instead of drawing it on the panel.

The following code will create an `ImageIcon` that you can just add to the `JPanel`.

```
ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myimage.jpeg");
```

This uses a fancy way to load the pic so that it will work when put into a Jar file.

Comment: I'v tried it, I have no errors but nothing appears on the frame except the buttons.

Comment: @firestruq, I added something else you may wanna try to my answer.

Comment: ImageIcon will work just like the ImageIO code that I posted in my answer.