# Variable name of Swing component in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have an application that is currently using over 200 buttons, each of which returns the String of their variable name. Is there any way to do this? Setting the name property for each of these would be far too time consuming.

Comment: This reeks of a bad fix for a bad design.  It would probably be quicker to redesign the app., though that depends on details not obvious to anyone here but you.  Why do you want to identify buttons by `String`, what advantage or feature does that provide to the app. or the end user?

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection of buttons:

```
ActionListener theActionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getName());
    }
};

List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton("Button " + (i + 1));
    button.setName("Button " + (i + 1));
    button.addActionListener(theActionListener);
    buttons.add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `JButton#putClientProperty` for identifying concrete JButton

```
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

and get from `ActionListener` (for example)

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
}
```

- but proper way for `JButton` should be to use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead of [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)