# Invoking a constructor with a file as an argument

Tags: java

I have a class `SpellingSuggestor`, whose constructor has the signature

---

`public SpellingSuggestor(File file) throws IOException { // something }`

I want to invoke its constructor from another class. The code goes something like this

```
public class NLPApplications
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String w= "randomword";
        URL url = getClass().getResource("big.txt");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());

        System.out.println((new SpellingSuggestor(file)).correct(w));   
    }
}
```

But the above shows error in the `URL url..` line saying

1. URL cannot be resolved to a type.
2. cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object.

What is going wrong ?

---

I looked at this question  [How to pass a text file as a argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309899/how-to-pass-a-text-file-as-a-argument). I am not comfortable with handling files in Java and so this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getclass()` is a non-static method and you can not make reference from static main method.

why it is so? [find here it is already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java) by [danben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217332/danben)

And work around is -

```
NLPApplications.class.getClass().getResource("big.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

Import :

```
import java.net.URL;
```

Use the class literal:

```
URL url = NLPApplications.class.getResource("big.txt");
```

Comment: Even then, it gives an error saying "URL cannot be resolved to a type."

Answer (score 2):

because you are trying to access a non-static method in static Main method which is not allowed, you have to use `TheClassName.class` instead of `getClass()`.