# How can I test that an image has been sent to a user on a chat application

Tags: gherkin

I've got a chat application I'm doing Gherkin for and one of the features I'll be adding is the ability to send images of various types, I just don't know how to write this up. Could it be?

```
Given the following users exist:
| Username |
| Alice    |
| Bob      |
When "Alice" sends "Bob" "Image A"
Then "Bob" can see "Image A"
```

Is "Image A" the url to the image? And, if it is, where does the image reside for the test itself?

Comment: This is a common programming problem where you need to store image location in a variable and pass that variable as argument. You can pass that variable name from gherkin feature file. See Here for storing file location, hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309899/how-to-pass-a-text-file-as-a-argument

Comment: @AbirKhan From what you describe I'd need a separate folder containing actual images to test and reference those as "featureimages/imagea.jpg/". Thanks. Feel free to stick this as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks @TheMightyLIama. Added answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common programming problem where you need to store image location in a variable and pass that variable as argument. You can pass that variable name from gherkin feature file. See Here for storing file location, hope this helps:

[How to pass a text file as a argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309899/how-to-pass-a-text-file-as-a-argument)