# How to specify the correct URL to a file in a Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, url, javafx, path

Okay. So I have tried doing this for a few hours know, and I know there are a lot of topics on the subject, like for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437382/how-do-relative-file-paths-work-in-eclipse) thread. But I've tried everything suggested in that thread and a few others, with no success.

My project hierarchy (and package hierarchy) looks like this: 
myProject/src/com/company/app/view

And the class in which I'm trying to link to another file in the project is in the last directory, "view".

And the file I'm trying to link to is placed in 
"myProject/src/com/company/app/" and is named "stylesheet.css".

If I do `System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());` I get the following path: "C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\myProject". Shouldn't this mean that I should specify an absolute path from myProject? In that case the path to my stylesheet would be "src/com/company/app/stylesheet.css", right? However, that doesn't work. I've also tried adding a slash in the beginning of that URL, which didn't work either.

I'm trying to add the stylesheet to a JavaFX DialogPane in my class. Like this:
`dialogPane.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");` and I've also tried this:
`dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());`

The first version never works, but the second version works if I put stylesheet.css at the same location as my class. But when I try to find the stylesheet at its proper place, e.g:

`dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("src/com/company/app/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());`

I get a `NullPointerException`.

If I could just specify a path relative to the class location from the parent directory as you can in HTML, e.g "../stylesheet.css", that would be the answer. But it seems like you can't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("com/company/app/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());?

Comment: Gah! That actually worked... Thanks! Why isn't the "src" part required?

Comment: The root of a java project is usually the src folder. This is the reason why usually package declarations also start with com. I will add this as an answer. Please accept it.

Comment: Typically, your IDE will create independent directory structures for your source code and your compiled code. (Eclipse defaults to `src` and `bin`, so you will likely find a `bin` folder with the compiled code and resources.) When you run an application, of course, you run from the compiled code, not from the source code, so your working directory is `bin`. It has a structure under it which more or less mirrors the structure *under* `src` (not under the project directory directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the resource from the path com/company/app/styleshe‌​et.css, i.e.

`dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("com/company/app/styleshe‌​et.css").toExternalForm());`