# How do I reference a text file from within an Eclipse JUnit java class ?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following workspace directory structure  :

[image]

And I thought that I could refer to the text file just using relative paths :

```
"src/main/resources/test/binary_Message.txt"
```

But this is not registering for some reason.

Comment: I am wondering did you miss 'config' in your relative path? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437382/how-do-relative-file-paths-work-in-eclipse.

Comment: @wannadream  - !!!! I did , oh I feel so silly   , thanks alot

Comment: The path you need to give is as it is stored in the classpath, not the file system.

Answer (score 2):

`getClass().getResource("/config/test/binary_Message.txt");`

Btw, it would make more sense to put the file under `src/test/resources` if it is really meant for testing only.