# How to add folder of property files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, filereader, properties-file, eclipse-neon

I shifted my project from tomcat to eclipse. All files are working fine but the folder containing property files are not working.

What I did so far:

1. Added folder in project -> build
2. created a source folder in project/src root and moved all
3. Set the classpath environment variables
4. Changed path with //, first folder without / etc.

but nothing worked for me. Here is screen shot:

[image]

Please advise where I am making mistake?
My OS is windows 8 but I have to deploy on CentOS
IDE: eclipse neon 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours I found the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437382/how-do-relative-file-paths-work-in-eclipse)

Copying solution here:

```
URL url = ConfigReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("lang/global/settings.properties");
String filename = url.getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be just `/lang/global/settings.properties` without `main`

Comment: I just checked but same error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: \lang\global\settings.properties (The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: In tomcat my project is working fine but in eclipse its killed me to correct the properties file path

Comment: @Devdas just replaye FileInputStream with ConfigReader.class.getResourceAsStream();

Comment: InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(ConfigReader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)),"UTF-8");            but its giving error. Not compiling

Comment: @Devdas dude remove `FileInputStream`.

Comment: InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(ConfigReader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)),"UTF-8");  but still showing red cross sign on the left side of line

Comment: I tried with full path (absolute path and its working) but why its not understanding eclipse folder structure?

Comment: I told you to ommit the 'main` part already. I bet your filename still has it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/lang/global/settings.properties");
```

If this doesn't works, you can check it out these links: [mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/), [crunchify](https://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am hitting my heading for the last 10 hours and googled a lot. I already tried this solution but the problem is my properties file are UTF. I mean containing Arabic, Perisan and English data. with InputStream utf not works that's why I used InputStreamReader instead