# Load txt's file into Java application and save it to XML's file

Tags: java, xml

I read the next answer about [load file into java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639/how-should-i-load-files-into-my-java-application).

I need to write a program that load .txt, which contains a list of records. After I parse it, I need to match the records (with conditions that I will check), and save the result to XML's file.

I am stuck on this issue, and I will happy for answer to next questions:

1. How I load the .txt file into Java?
2. After I load the file, how I can acsses to the information into it? for example, How I can asked if the first line of one of the records is equal to "1";
3. How I export the result to XML's file.

Comment: So you want the code or pseudo code?

Comment: @home: I would like for some highlights how to do it in Java. pseudo code will be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[one](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml): you need a sample-code for reading a file line by line

[two](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29): the split-method of a string might be helpful. For instance getting the number of the first element if information is seperated by a space

```
String myLine;
String[] components = myLine.split(" ");
if(components != null && components.length >= 1) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(components[0]);
    ....
}
```

[three](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml): you can just write it like any text-file, or use any [XML-Writer](http://www.google.de/#q=java+xmlwriter) you want

Answer (score 1):

1. [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)
2. [`Integer.parseInt(1stLine)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
3. There are a plethora of choices.

   1. Create POJO's to represent the records and write them using [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)
   2. [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html)
   3. [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html)..