# adding file path in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and facing a small problem with loading a file. Basically what i want to do is load an xml file present in the same src folder in a java file that is also in the same folder.

file structure is like this project > src > example.xml, program.java

I want to load example.xml in program.java but whatever i do it keeps on saying wrong path specified. My code is

```
File xml = new File("/Project/src/exmaple.xml");
```

But its not working at all, can anyone help please?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the quick responses guys i solved it with the help from @Exupery and have also answered my won question so that its helpful for others too!

Comment: You're using an absolute path, is Project a root level folder? Try just "src/example.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How stupid of me i just figured it out myself... so the corrected code is

```
File xml = new File("src/example.xml");
```

Thanks to @Exupery!

Answer (score 0):

If your path starts with a `/` then it is assumed that the path is absolute. Is the file located at `/Project/src/exmaple.xml`? If not, you need to provide the correct, absolute path or a relative path.

When running Eclipse projects, the relative path is usually starts in the root catalogue of your project, usually containing the `src` and `target` directories.

Comment: No my actual main folder is project which has src folder in it having both the files

Answer (score 0):

InputStream inputStream = 
                YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");

from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639/how-should-i-load-files-into-my-java-application)